# Why my slick slider with indicator not working?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, slider, slick.js

I have a question about slick sliders. I've made a slider with a slick, I want to create an indicator for each slide. I have the code in [Codepen](https://codepen.io/fikryrmdhna/pen/XWdROJX), please check.

**What I Want**

When I was on the first slide, the active border was on the slider 1 indicator, when I was on slide 2 the indicator was on the slider 2 indicator as below.

[image]

[image]

I've been looking for several ways but still nothing I can use. if you know how, please help me. Because I don't know how to make custom indicators like that. I need your help please.

**HTML**

```
        <section id="bannerHome">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12" id="homeBanner">
                        <div class="slider-banner">
                            <div class="item">
                                <div class="content">
                                    <div class="first-layer">
                                        <p>01</p>
                                        <p>01</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="second-layer">
                                        <div class="title">
                                            <h1>
                                                Digitalisasi dan Industri 4.0: Manajemen data untuk perkembangan tren transformasi
                                            </h1>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="date">
                                            <p>Lintasarta</p>
                                            <p>July 30, 2020</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                                <div class="content">
                                    <div class="first-layer">
                                        <p>02</p>
                                        <p>02</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="second-layer">
                                        <div class="title">
                                            <h1>
                                                Digitalisasi dan Industri 4.0: Manajemen data untuk perkembangan tren transformasi
                                            </h1>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="date">
                                            <p>Lintasarta</p>
                                            <p>July 30, 2020</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slider-indicator">
                            <div class="slider-1 active">
                                For Slider 1
                            </div>
                            <div class="slider-2">
                                For Slider 2
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

**CSS**

```
#bannerHome{
    height: 100vh ;
    background-color: #c6c6c6;

    #homeBanner {
        height: 100vh ;
        padding: 0;

        .slider-banner {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;

            .item {
                height: 100vh ;

                .content{
                    display: flex;
                    flex-direction: column;
                    justify-content: center;
                    position: relative;
                    height: 100%;
                    padding: 0 10%;

                    .first-layer{
                        position: absolute;
                        top: 45%;
                        left: 0;
                        transform: translate(0, -45%);

                        p {
                            color: #fff;
                            font-size: 350px;
                            opacity: .15;

                            &:nth-child(2){
                                position: absolute;
                                font-size:45px;
                                top: 40%;
                                left: 25%;
                                transform: translate(-25%, -40%);
                                opacity: 1;

                                &::before{
                                    content: '';
                                    position: absolute;
                                    width: 20px;
                                    height: 3px;
                                    background-color: #fff;
                                    top: 10px;
                                    left: -50px;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    .second-layer{
                        .title{
                            width:55%;

                            h1{
                                color: #fff;
                                font-size: 25px;
                                line-height: 25px;
                            }
                        }

                        .date{
                            display: flex;
                            position: relative;
                            margin-top: 30px;
                            
                            p{
                                color: #e6e6e6;
                                margin-right: 10px;
                                font-size: 15px;
            
                                &:nth-child(2){
                                    padding-left: 10px;
                                    position: relative;
                                  display:none;
            
                                    &::before{
                                        content: '';
                                        position: absolute;
                                        left: 0;
                                        bottom: 0;
                                        border-left: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
                                        height: 100%;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

.arrowBannerLeft{
    position: absolute;
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    top: 55%;
    left: 5%;
    transform: translate(-5%, -55%);
    z-index: 1;

    &:focus{
        outline: none;
        box-shadow: none;
    }
}

.arrowBannerRight{
    position: absolute;
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    top: 48%;
    left: 5%;
    transform: translate(-5%, -48%);
    z-index: 1;

    &:focus{
        outline: none;
        box-shadow: none;
    }
}

.slider-indicator {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    bottom: 15%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -15%);
    z-index: 1;

    .slider-1, .slider-2 {
        color: #fff;
        padding: 10px 40px;
        border-top: 1px solid #000;

        &.active{
            border-top: 3px solid #EB961D;
        }
    }
}
```

**JS**

```
var bannerSlider = $('.slider-banner');

$('.slider-banner').slick({
   // arrows: false,
   // dots: true,
   slidesToShow: 1,
   slidesToScroll: 1,
   prevArrow: "<button class='arrowBannerLeft'><img src='assets/img/component/icon/arrowBlockLeft.svg' class='img-fluid'></button>",
   nextArrow: "<button class='arrowBannerRight'><img src='assets/img/component/icon/arrowBlockRight.svg' class='img-fluid'></button>",
});

$(".arrowBannerLeft").on("click", function() {
    $('.slider-banner').slick("slickNext");
    var currentSlideIndex = $(".slider-banner").slick("slickCurrentSlide")
});

$(".arrowBannerRight").on("click", function() {
   $(".slider-banner").slick("slickPrev");
   var currentSlideIndex = $(".slider-banner").slick("slickCurrentSlide");
});

$('.slider-banner').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
   var active_val = parseInt($(".slider-indicator .slide").addClass('active'));
   var currentSlideIndex = nextSlide;

});
```

Comment: are you using bootstrap also?

Comment: yea bro, i'm using bootstrap. why? @gpl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this snippet:

```css
#bannerHome{
height: 100vh ;
background-color: #c6c6c6;

#homeBanner {
    height: 100vh ;
    padding: 0;

    .slider-banner {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;

        .item {
            height: 100vh ;

            .content{
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                justify-content: center;
                position: relative;
                height: 100%;
                padding: 0 10%;

                .first-layer{
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 45%;
                    left: 0;
                    transform: translate(0, -45%);

                    p {
                        color: #fff;
                        font-size: 350px;
                        opacity: .15;

                        &:nth-child(2){
                            position: absolute;
                            font-size:45px;
                            top: 40%;
                            left: 25%;
                            transform: translate(-25%, -40%);
                            opacity: 1;

                            &::before{
                                content: '';
                                position: absolute;
                                width: 20px;
                                height: 3px;
                                background-color: #fff;
                                top: 10px;
                                left: -50px;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                .second-layer{
                    .title{
                        width:55%;

                        h1{
                            color: #fff;
                            font-size: 25px;
                            line-height: 25px;
                        }
                    }

                    .date{
                        display: flex;
                        position: relative;
                        margin-top: 30px;

                        p{
                            color: #e6e6e6;
                            margin-right: 10px;
                            font-size: 15px;

                            &:nth-child(2){
                                padding-left: 10px;
                                position: relative;
                                display:none;

                                &::before{
                                    content: '';
                                    position: absolute;
                                    left: 0;
                                    bottom: 0;
                                    border-left: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
                                    height: 100%;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}

.arrowBannerLeft{
position: absolute;
background: transparent;
border: none;
top: 55%;
left: 5%;
transform: translate(-5%, -55%);
z-index: 1;

&:focus{
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
}

.arrowBannerRight{
position: absolute;
background: transparent;
border: none;
top: 48%;
left: 5%;
transform: translate(-5%, -48%);
z-index: 1;

&:focus{
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
}

.slider-indicator {
position: absolute;
display: flex;
bottom: 15%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -15%);
z-index: 1;
}

.slider-1, .slider-2 {
color: #fff;
padding: 10px 40px;
border-top: 1px solid #000;
}

.slider-1.active, .slider-2.active{
border-top: 3px solid #EB961D;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.css" integrity="sha512-wR4oNhLBHf7smjy0K4oqzdWumd+r5/+6QO/vDda76MW5iug4PT7v86FoEkySIJft3XA0Ae6axhIvHrqwm793Nw==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.css" integrity="sha512-6lLUdeQ5uheMFbWm3CP271l14RsX1xtx+J5x2yeIDkkiBpeVTNhTqijME7GgRKKi6hCqovwCoBTlRBEC20M8Mg==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>


    <section id="bannerHome">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12" id="homeBanner">
                    <div class="slider-banner">
                        <div class="item">
                            <div class="content">
                                <div class="first-layer">
                                    <p>01</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="second-layer">
                                    <div class="title">
                                        <h1>
                                            Digitalisasi dan Industri 4.0: Manajemen data untuk perkembangan tren transformasi
                                        </h1>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="date">
                                        <p>Lintasarta</p>
                                        <p>July 30, 2020</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <div class="content">
                                <div class="first-layer">
                                    <p>02</p>

                                </div>
                                <div class="second-layer">
                                    <div class="title">
                                        <h1>
                                            Digitalisasi dan Industri 4.0: Manajemen data untuk perkembangan tren transformasi
                                        </h1>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="date">
                                        <p>Lintasarta</p>
                                        <p>July 30, 2020</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slider-indicator">
                      <div class="slider-1 active">
                          For Slider 1
                      </div>
                      <div class="slider-2">
                          For Slider 2
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </section>


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- Bootstrap tooltips -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.4/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js" integrity="sha512-XtmMtDEcNz2j7ekrtHvOVR4iwwaD6o/FUJe6+Zq+HgcCsk3kj4uSQQR8weQ2QVj1o0Pk6PwYLohm206ZzNfubg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
      var bannerSlider = $('.slider-banner');

      $('.slider-banner').slick({
                // arrows: false,
                // dots: true,
                slidesToShow: 1,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
                prevArrow: "<button class='arrowBannerLeft'><i class='fas fa-chevron-left'></i></button>",
                nextArrow: "<button class='arrowBannerRight'><i class='fas fa-chevron-right'></i></button>",
            });

      $(".arrowBannerLeft").on("click", function() {
        $('.slider-banner').slick("slickNext");
        var currentSlideIndex = $(".slider-banner").slick("slickCurrentSlide")
    });
      $(".arrowBannerRight").on("click", function() {
        $(".slider-banner").slick("slickPrev");
        var currentSlideIndex = $(".slider-banner").slick("slickCurrentSlide");
    });

      $('.slider-banner').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
        $(".slider-"+(nextSlide+1)).addClass('active');
        $(".slider-"+(currentSlide+1)).removeClass('active');
        var currentSlideIndex = nextSlide;
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```